# ng-repeat gets refreshed when an item clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is `html`:

```
    <div class="main" ng-controller="companies">
        <ul style="list-style: none;">
            <li ng-repeat="company in companies | orderBy:'name' | filter:companies_filter">
                <a href="#!/companies/{{company.id}}" ng-click="companySelected(company)">
                    {{company.name}}
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

This is `router.js`:

```
...
        .when('/companies', {
            templateUrl: '../html/companies.html',
            controller: 'companies'
        })
        .when('/companies/:companyId', {
            templateUrl: '../html/companies.html'
        });
....
```

This is working:

```
$scope.companySelected = function(company) {
    console.log(company);
}
```

The list is pretty huge. If I scroll down to bottom and click on a company, the list gets back to the top. Same happens when I enter company name to filter and click, again, it gets back to its initial view. How can I fix it so that it stays where it is?

Comment: Can you post the code for companySelected?

Comment: @MikeFeltman, done. Nothing special though, just `console.log(company);`, and it's working.

Comment: Open your controller up in the debugger and place a break point in the constructor code. It sounds like it's reloading your page.

Comment: @MikeFeltman, could you please share sample code or link to it? I am not able to figure out how to debug. Thanks!

Comment: Specific debugging instructions are going to vary based on what browser you're using. The ability to debug and trace code is an essential skill that you must have to do web development. I'd recommend you Google something like "debugging JavaScript with whatever browser you're using."  There are tons of resources available for this.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for **$anchorScroll**.

Here is the documentation: [anchorScroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll)

When you return from company page to the list, you might need to add hash Id of the element that you clicked earlier. To that, you first need to add ID to li element like below.

```
<li id={{company.id}} ng-repeat="company in companies | orderBy:'name' | filter:companies_filter">
                <a href="#!/companies/{{company.id}}" ng-click="companySelected(company)">
                    {{company.name}}
                </a>
</li>
```

while coming back to list page, call `$anchorScroll();` You can send hash as a parameter in the anchorscroll or update the location hash like below before calling `$anchorScroll();`

```
$location.hash('id_value');
```

Comment: Can you post your code. Also, did you call anchorscroll() with hash parameter?

Comment: Updated my answer to update the location hash. see if that helps